# Percentage height/width property not working while parent div with display: -moz-box;

Tags: html, css

I'm stucked with a problem while I'm setting height/width in percentage for a child div.

Parent div has property `display: -moz-box`. It will work when I remove that property.

Something like:

```
<div class='parent' style="display: -moz-box;">
  <div class='child' style="height:100%;width:70%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set a `width & height of the parent container` to an absolute (in px) or relative value (in %,vh,vw,etc). Then you can make use of % width of the child element which is in `relation to your direct parent element`.

And it's `display:box` which works on any of the browsers, but is outdated and I don't see any use of it. You can make use of flexbox as display:flex is need be or if you have to display it as block element, use display:block.

```html
<div class='parent' style=" width:100px;height:100px;display:box;">
  <div class='child' style="height:100%;width:70%;background:red;">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='parent' style="width:100%;height:100px;display:box;">
  <div class='child' style="height:100%;width:70%;background:green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had added display: -moz-box; because of in my scenario , height and width is dynamic (can be decided by end-user in px or percentage) . So it might be the case user is defining the height/width in px more than the main container height/width. So in this scenario sub-container is not visible properly(cutting from top,bottom,left,right), thats why added display: -moz-box; property.

Comment: Working in pixels case but not for percentage one

Comment: The height needs to be fixed in an absolute value, either the parents need to have or it should have a % with relation to an absolute value to the parent's parent. % doesn't just take any % on its own, its always in relation to its parent container's dimensions.

Comment: parent has height and width of 100% already. and child has position: relative;

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following css properties for `child` div:

```
.child{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Then you can set `height` and `width` in `%` and `px` as well.

Comment: Then It will not work with the case when user will set height/width in px more than the parent container height/width.

Comment: It works. `Child div` moves out of `parent div`. Try it.